# Как заполнить массив, перехватывая исключения

Tags: java, массивы, исключения

есть метод, который заполняет одну строку двумерного массива с консоли.
на вход получает сам массив (Matrix) и его номер строки, которую будем заполнять.
хочу сначала проверить все ли числа в введенной строке. Если ввели не число, выдать сообщение и начать считывать заново, но если ввести сюда что-то кроме чисел, программа будет выводить сообщение в бесконечном цикле.

```
public static double[][] read(double[][] Matrix,int StringNumber)
{

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    scanner.useDelimiter(";\\s*");
    boolean isGood;
    double [] Mat = new double[Matrix.length];


    do
    {
        isGood = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < Matrix.length; i++)
        {
            try
            {
               Mat[i] =  scanner.nextDouble();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                isGood = false;
                scanner.next();
            }
        }
        if (isGood)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Matrix.length; i++)
            {

                Matrix[i][StringNumber] = Mat[i];
            }

        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Вводите числа!!!!");
            Zero(Mat);
        }
    }while (!isGood);
    return Matrix;

}
```

Comment: Нужна очистка потока ввода, ещё isGood всегда будет false если попадёт в исключение хотя бы раз. После do следует поставить isGood=true;

Comment: `isGood = true;` - добавьте после `do {`

Comment: `scanner.nextDouble();` в первом цикле съест весь пользовательский ввод же, и если пользователь введет все правильно, то ему придется повторить ввод второй раз. Либо сразу заполняйте матрицу в первом цикле, а второй выбросьте, либо, если нужно менять значение в матрице только если пользователь ввел успешно всю строку, сохраняйте ввод в отдельный массив, и потом копируйте.

Comment: еще совет Komdosh реализуйте: при исключении вызывайте `scanner.next()`, т.к. если `nextDouble()` не завершился успешно, сканнер не продвигается к следующему элементу. Можно так же циклы местами поменять - требовать ввести число до бесконечности, а если число введено - увеличивать номер столбца

Comment: Спасибо! 
все дело было в том, что nextDouble() дальше не шел..

Answer (score 1):

Вот мой вариант с рекурсией, надеюсь будет полезен.

```
public class Number {
public static double[][] read(double[][] matrix, int stringNumber) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    try {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[stringNumber].length; j++) {
            System.out.print("Enter number: ");
            matrix[stringNumber][j] = scanner.nextDouble();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("error! make input again");
        read(matrix, stringNumber);
    }
    return matrix;
}

public static void consoleOutput(double[][] matrix){
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        System.out.println();
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[][] matrix = new double[3][3];
    consoleOutput(Number.read(matrix, 1));

}}
```

десятичная часть вводиться после запятой.